# Can't use rubygems

Tags: rubygems

I think I need to do a fresh uninstall/install of rails, but I am unable to do so because my "gem" command is no longer working. When I type 'gem' I get the following error, but as you see, I have `usr/local/bin` in my PATH

```
caemlyn:rubygems-1.8.6 tonybeninate$ gem
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gem: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
caemlyn:rubygems-1.8.6 tonybeninate$ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem

caemlyn:rubygems-1.8.6 tonybeninate$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec
```

For what it's worth, I am on Lion now; Please help. Thank you.

UPDATE
Thanks to the suggestions I am a lot closer now. I installed rails 3.0.7 with no hitch! However, when I try to run rails, I get the following error:

```
caemlyn:PhotoBlog tonybeninate$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

But it's clearly there:

```
caemlyn:PhotoBlog tonybeninate$ which rails
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/rails
```

Thoughts?

Never mind, after following this a little more closely I got things working https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the gem binary is linked to a ruby version that no longer works (maybe it was linked to some libraries that were updated in lion). Do you have similar issues with irb or the ruby interpreter itself?

My suggestion would be to do the following:

1. upgrade XCode so that you have the developer tools, if you haven't already done this. Uninstall the previous version via `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --all` before installing the latest
2. Clear out any system gems you have installed.
3. Install rvm and use this to manage ruby, rubygems, and gemsets.
4. Make sure that your path is correctly using rvm version of ruby and rubygems over anything already installed on your system. `rvm info`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post. RVM has fixed almost everything! everything is working just fine, except I've installed rails 3.0.7 but when I type `rails` it says it's not installed, any thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to reinstall rails into the same ruby version + gemset that you're using for this project. Remember to not use 'sudo' to install gems any more. `rvm info` and `gem list` should help you debug where ruby is / isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RVM? As far as I remember, RVM will install gems for you, and the version it installs should be working.

Link: https://rvm.io